# Angular2 Router navigate is not working in service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service, router

Now I am trying to use Angular2 Router.navigate, but it isn't working.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

    constructor(
        public _http: Http,
        public _router: Router
        ) 
    {
    }

    public sendPostRequestWithParams(url, params) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        return this._http.post(url, params, {headers: headers})
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleServerError);
    }

    public handleServerError(error: Response) {
        let jError = error.json() && error.json()['error'];
        if (jError == 'Unauthenticated.') {
            alert("You are not unauthenticated. Please login correctly!");
            this._router.navigate(['login']);
            return Observable.throw("You are not unauthenticated. Please login correctly!");
        }
        return Observable.throw(error.json() || 'Server error'); // Observable.throw() is undefined at runtime using Webpack
    }

}
```

But when calling handleServerError, it shows error "Cannot read property navigate of undefined".

Is it impossible to use Router in Service?

Comment: Change `.catch(this.handleServerError);` to `.catch(this.handleServerError.bind(this));` . You should close this as duplicate. There are other solutions which you can do in the link. I highly suggest you to read it.

Comment: @echonax, This works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, already done!

Comment: Nice, glad you figured it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change below line

this._router.navigate(['login']);  *=>* **this._router.navigate(['/login']);**